# iOS - how can I programmatically calculate the time limit to record audio/video with the known file limit size

Tags: ios

I have tried to google a lot but it seems like no one have done it beforein iOS. 
My issue is: my server only allow the client to upload the video / audio / image file with limited size (e.g: 30M for video, 1M for audio). With that limit, I want to figure how much time the users are allow to record audio / video. This calculation must consider the difference devices for example the iPad 3 has better camera then ipad 2 so we will have less time to record the video. 
I am wondering if we can programmatically calculate the time limit base on the known file size.

Thanks, 
Luan.

Comment: If you are using AV Foundation I beleive you can set a minimum amount of remaining space and then record till you hit it. No need to know ahead what the size is.

Answer (score 1):

When working with large amounts of data such as video and audio, compression should play a part in your calculation.

Compression results can vary greatly depending on what you are recording and as a result it would be unrealistic to try to forecast a certain maximum duration.

I can think of two options:

- Predetermine very restrictive recording times per device (I believe it is possible in iOS to tell an iPad3 from an iPad2)
- Figure out a way to re-encode a smaller part of the video until it is within limits.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Cantgetright has the reason this is hard described perfectly.

What you really care about is megapixels of the camera (definition), worst case storage size of one second of video, and how many free megs are on the phone as well.

If you know most of these elements, time can be the constraint by which you determine the last one.

Always overestimate size to guarantee it'll work no matter what. People don't know how big 5secs of video is on their iDevices anyway so you can be stingy with allotted time